# AWS - dynamoDB price and usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to make serverless service. Service would be made like this.

> API gateway -> lambda -> dynamoDB

1. DynamoDB will count sum of read/write real usage time? If I read dynamoDB hourly and each read time would be 1 sec, then

> ( 24 hour * 30 days * 1 sec ) / 60 sec * DyanmoDB read hour price =
>   real cost price?

2. What if I send 100 requests in a sec with 10 unit DynamoDB, DB would not be able to read as much as I request?

Comment: See [burst capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you exceed your read or write capacity that you provisioned, you requested will/may be rejected and your application will need to have a provision to retry the read/write.

Dynamodb will sometimes absorb read/writes beyond what you have provisioned, so you might get away with it sometimes, but it's not guaranteed, so you still need to account for it in your design.

Comment: Could you check pricing question for me?

Comment: Look at the pricing example here: https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/, you should be able to extrapolate from that.

Comment: I've seen it. I want to know even if I use dynamodb not full time, would aws charge for full time or just each time I used it?

Comment: Here is the AWS calculator - and also keep in mind that AWS has a very generous, non-expiring free-tier for DynamoDB (25 reads and writes a second): https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html